# Error in installing ATF in eclipse

Tags: ajax, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse JUNO->install new software->http://download.eclipse.org/tools/atf/updates/0.3.0

but it gives me this error

**Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: AJAX Tools Framework Webtools Integration (Incubation) 0.3.0.v201006041600-15-7zCN3HbXIOZQuUeDRRMG (org.eclipse.atf.feature.feature.group 0.3.0.v201006041600-15-7zCN3HbXIOZQuUeDRRMG)
  Missing requirement: AJAX Tools Framework Mozilla IDE (Incubation) 0.3.0.v201006041600-17K-DZRDIXEqJdCQQLF (org.eclipse.atf.mozilla.ide.feature.feature.group 0.3.0.v201006041600-17K-DZRDIXEqJdCQQLF) requires 'org.mozilla.xpcom.feature.feature.group 1.8.1' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AJAX Tools Framework Webtools Integration (Incubation) 0.3.0.v201006041600-15-7zCN3HbXIOZQuUeDRRMG (org.eclipse.atf.feature.feature.group 0.3.0.v201006041600-15-7zCN3HbXIOZQuUeDRRMG)
    To: org.eclipse.atf.mozilla.ide.feature.feature.group [0.3.0.v201006041600-17K-DZRDIXEqJdCQQLF]vCannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: AJAX Tools Framework Webtools Integration (Incubation) 0.3.0.v201006041600-15-7zCN3HbXIOZQuUeDRRMG (org.eclipse.atf.feature.feature.group 0.3.0.v201006041600-15-7zCN3HbXIOZQuUeDRRMG)
  Missing requirement: AJAX Tools Framework Mozilla IDE (Incubation) 0.3.0.v201006041600-17K-DZRDIXEqJdCQQLF (org.eclipse.atf.mozilla.ide.feature.feature.group 0.3.0.v201006041600-17K-DZRDIXEqJdCQQLF) requires 'org.mozilla.xpcom.feature.feature.group 1.8.1' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AJAX Tools Framework Webtools Integration (Incubation) 0.3.0.v201006041600-15-7zCN3HbXIOZQuUeDRRMG (org.eclipse.atf.feature.feature.group 0.3.0.v201006041600-15-7zCN3HbXIOZQuUeDRRMG)
    To: org.eclipse.atf.mozilla.ide.feature.feature.group [0.3.0.v201006041600-17K-DZRDIXEqJdCQQLF]**

thanks

Comment: mozilla is not installed.Is that the basic problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You should "install new software > http://beta.zend.com/studio-eclipse/updates-extra/9_0" first. (Just try)

Please Check the site (http://wiki.eclipse.org/ATF/Installing)...

Comment: thanks i got the answer earlier but forgot to answer here .Since you are right so me marking your answer correct :)